# Functionality of take! and put! and Channels in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to run something that looks like this:

```
y = @parallel (min) for i in collection
    f(i)
end
```

where `f(i)` is a function that's essentially a `while` loop that counts how many iterations it takes to fulfill its conditions. At the beginning, one of the termination conditions is a predetermined number of iterations, `n`. However, if `f(i)` ever returns less than `n` then ideally I would want to replace `n` with the value of `f(i)` (e.g., since I am looking for the minimum `f(i)`, if `f(j)` is `m` I would want all other loops to stop checking if they reach `m` iterations).

I'm new to parallel computing and so I'm likely misinterpreting the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/parallel/), but I think that I should be able to do something like this:

```
x = Channel{Int64}(1)
put!(x,n)

y = @parallel (min) for i in collection
    f(i,x)
end

close(x)
```

where I've modified `f` to take a `Channel` parameter and now it looks something like this:

```
@everywhere function f(item,chan)
    going = true
    count = 0
    while (going)
        going = false
        # perform some operations
        if (count < fetch(chan) && !conditions_met())
            # conditions_met checks the other termination conditions
            going = true
            count += 1
        end
    end

    count += 1

    if (count < fetch(chan))
        take!(chan)
        put!(chan,count)
    end

    return count
end
```

If I replace the first `count < fetch(chan)` with `count < n` and remove the other `if` block/`Channel` code, the script runs fine. But, since `n` will be several orders of magnitude larger than the minimum `f(i)`, if I could do something like I've described it would speed up computation significantly. Is this something I should be able to do and if so, am I approaching this correctly?

Right now I am experiencing the following error (running with 4 procs):

```
ERROR (unhandled task failure): On worker 3:
cannot resize array with shared data
 in shift! at array.jl:501
 in take! at channels.jl:54
 in f at /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:98
 [inlined code] from /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:126
 in anonymous at no file:0
 in anonymous at multi.jl:913
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:651
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:913
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:737
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:740
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1519
ERROR: LoadError: On worker 2:
cannot resize array with shared data
 in shift! at array.jl:501
 in take! at channels.jl:54
 in f at /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:98
 [inlined code] from /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:126
 in anonymous at no file:0
 in anonymous at multi.jl:913
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:651
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:913
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
 in preduce at multi.jl:1523
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:1532
 in anonymous at expr.jl:113
 [inlined code] from /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:125
 in anonymous at no file:0
while loading /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl, in expression starting on line 121
ERROR (unhandled task failure): On worker 4:
cannot resize array with shared data
 in shift! at array.jl:501
 in take! at channels.jl:54
 in f at /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:98
 [inlined code] from /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:126
 in anonymous at no file:0
 in anonymous at multi.jl:913
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:651
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:913
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:737
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:740
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1519
ERROR (unhandled task failure): On worker 5:
cannot resize array with shared data
 in shift! at array.jl:501
 in take! at channels.jl:54
 in f at /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:98
 [inlined code] from /home/michael/Documents/julia/script.jl:126
 in anonymous at no file:0
 in anonymous at multi.jl:913
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:651
 [inlined code] from multi.jl:913
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:737
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:740
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1519
```

where line `98` is the `take!(chan)` statement in the function definition and line `126` is `f(i,x)` inside the parallel `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Channel`s implement CSP-like semantics for async communication, but they have no automated mechanism of sharing across parallel processes. You need to use `RemoteRef` for such purpose: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/#remoterefs-and-abstractchannels